# Is there a way to create a Personal Geodatabase in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, personal-geodatabase

Is there a way to create a Personal Geodatabase in QGIS?  I know QGIS can view Personal Geodatabases, but can one be created?  I have a project where the client is requiring a small spatial database (they are very low on the tech level, so I do not want to jump into PostGIS etc etc).  They also only use ArcGIS.  I would like to do the project in QGIS, hence my question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [GDAL docs](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_pgeo.html):

> OGR optionally supports reading ESRI Personal GeoDatabase .mdb files
>   via ODBC. Personal GeoDatabase is a Microsoft Access database with a
>   set of tables defined by ESRI for holding geodatabase metadata, and
>   with geometry for features held in a BLOB column in a custom format
>   (essentially Shapefile geometry fragments). This drivers accesses the
>   personal geodatabase via ODBC but does not depend on any ESRI
>   middle-ware.

Writing a personal geodatabase on the other hand, is another story. Access mdb is a proprietary file format and open source projects like QGIS tend to stay away from them. I did see an old open source project called [MDB Tools](http://mdbtools.sourceforge.net/faq.html) which aims to

> MDB Tools is an open source suite of libraries and utilities to read
>   (and soon write) MDB database files.

I'm not sure how far along their goal that project is though. So no,  I don't think you can create personal geodatabase files using QGIS as of now or any time soon.

As for your client's request, [@Ragi](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/1965/ragi-yaser-burhum) has just finished writing an [ArcGIS plugin that let's you use OGR sources](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/33162/292), this includes Spatialite and PostGIS. That way you can use ArcGIS and [PostGIS](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiOGR) ( or Spatialite, whichever you prefer ). You might want to give it a try.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 7):

QGIS uses the [OGR](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/) library for the majority of it's GIS format access.  The Personal GDB access falls under this grouping.

Based on the OGR Vector Format's page here:  [OGR Vector Formats](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_formats.html)

The [ESRI Personal GeoDatabase](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_pgeo.html) driver **does not** have Creation support.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question now - what alternative to 'geodatabase' is there in QGIS that could hold multiple layers with attribute tables in a single file. I did not find answer at first, but I found this question.

After some research I found that SpatiaLite database is nice replacement for it tutorial http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/digitizing_basics.html

Also I found that SpatiaLite is transferable between ArcGis and QGIS see this blog:  http://blog.geomusings.com/2013/08/07/spatialite-and-arcgis-10-dot-2/

Comment: I have been using SpatiaLite DBs in QGIS with great success.