# Documenting inability to Start Editing SQLite geodatabase layers in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, spatialite, sqlite, arcgis-10.2

I've recently started creating SQLite geodatabases using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop with both ST_GEOMETRY and SPATIALITE storage data types and was impressed by how easy this was to do.

I then tried to Start Editing them from ArcMap only to be blocked by an error:

> No editable layers.

and a warning

> The workspace containing this data cannot be edited.

[image]

I looked and could not find this limitation mentioned anywhere, and originally mistook it as SQLite being read-only to ArcGIS for Desktop.

Is the non-editability of SQLite within ArcMap edit sessions documented anywhere?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not strictly read-only access. You can load data via copy/paste and import into a SQLite or SpatiaLite database. Tables and feature classes can be appended to using append or Load Data.

You can edit the SQLite/SpatiaLite data **via code** as Insert/Update/Delete are supported.

What you can't do is open an edit session in ArcMap.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and documenting that here Lance and it is great to have your authority behind it.  Please do not be offended that I am about to remove your signature, which we do here because every post you make is already signed by [your user card](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/59752/lance-shipman) which is the ideal place for it.  If you want to also document this in the Help then perhaps this would be a suitable place: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/databases/sqlite-and-arcgis.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_E4F82E510ED443088D87F6226E982EBA

Answer (score 11):

In the [documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/SQLite_and_ArcGIS/019v0000001w000000/), it is alluded to that you cannot edit data in a SQLite database from ArcMap:

> You can connect from ArcGIS to an SQLite database to create maps and perform spatial analysis on your data.

However, the only place this appears to be explicitly stated by Esri is in the [ArcGIS Discussion Forum](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/91327-SQLite-Editing):

> Yes; you cannot edit data in a SQLite database from ArcMap.

Comment: Wow. That's pretty disheartening. I got a little excited when I heard "support for SQLite" in the list of what's new at 10.2. Nice how it never _really_ says that it's read-only access.

Comment: The 10.2 mobile apis (iOS, Android, and Windows) use SQLite under the hood for disconnected editing. But they're able to control that database so that it behaves like a file geodatabase. That's harder to do with a SQLite database in the wild.

Comment: After some test the only way to "create" features using ArcGIS Desktop I found is to **copy&paste** a feature class from an ArcGIS format (ex: File Geodatabase) to the sqlite database.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good solution but it could be workaround if you got a license: edit Spatialite or GeoPackage database is OK in ArcGIS Pro (tested on 2.7.3).