# Using SQLite for multi-editors in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, editing, sqlite

I am wondering if it is possible to use a SQLite for multiple editors in ArcGIS Desktop?

- ArcMap 10.1
- Small team, only five editors for now.
- Shared network drive

Need a quick and solution due to governance and budget constraints while waiting for funding for a real SQL environment and IT team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [commented by @Vince](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216007/using-sqlite-for-multi-editors-in-arcgis/282259#comment331051_216007):

> SQLite support wasn't included in ArcGIS [until
>   10.2](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/826/does-arcgis-for-desktop-support-spatialite).
>   Even at 10.3, it is NOT multi-user.  Non-enterprise geodatabase
>   support was added for PostgreSQL at ArcGIS 10.4.